# How to check is there any value from array (PHP)?

Tags: php, arrays, conditional-statements

I have the array and I want to check if there is any value from this array in my function.

Here is my code:

```
$values = [
    'value_1',
    'value_2',
    'value_3'
];

if (has_block( any value from $values ) {
    // stuff
}
```

So my point is: how to check if there is any value from array - maybe one, maybe all of them, without checking it by values itself like `if (has_block( 'value_1') || has_block'value_2' )`?

I tried like this:

```
$values = [
  'value_1',
  'value_2',
  'value_3'
];

$List = "'" . implode("', '", $values) . "'";
  
if (has_block( in_array($List, $values) ) ) {
    // stuff
}
```

Comment: Something like [in_​array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)?

Comment: Yes, I tried it, also with implode but still no good results

Comment: Maybe write expect result?

Comment: @brombeer I've added my tryouts in my posts above.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(isset($foo_array['somevalue']) || $foo_array['someothervalue'] === 'bla') {
    // proceed
}
```

OR

```
if(in_array("avalue", $foo_array)) {
    echo "Found It";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`array_intersect`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php). It will return new array with values that are in all arrays

```
$values = [
    'value_1',
    'value_2',
    'value_3'
];

$search = [
    'value_1',
    'value_5',
];

if (!empty(array_intersect($search, $values))) {
    // stuff
}
```